# In ionic 3 Ionic - Autocomplete location of Google places is detached from input box when we scroll down

Tags: google-maps, ionic-framework, ionic3

in ionic we are using ionic geolocation for google maps…In input of search box when we search any place and then after scroll down to app then autocomplete also scroll and detached from input search box design. I applied many CSS for attaching autocomplete with search input but not working properly. [image: when scroll then autocomplete detached from search box]

Below code is working fine in web-browser but not working in build.
**html file**

```
<ion-content class="bglightgray" #content padding>

    <div class="mapView">
        <div class="searchBar">
            <!-- <ion-searchbar placeholder="Search your Location" class="mapSearch" ></ion-searchbar> -->
            <div class="inp-wrap">

                <input id="MapInput" [(ngModel)]="mapname" class="mapSearch cs-mapSearch" type="text" placeholder="Search your Location" #MapInput>

                <div class="closeIcon" (click)="closeSearch()"></div>
                <div class="searchbarIcon"></div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <!-- <img src="assets/imgs/map.jpg" alt=""> -->
        <div #mapContainer id="mapContainer" [ngClass]=" { hideMap: !MapView}"></div>
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

**ts file**

```
import { Content, Events } from 'ionic-angular';
export class MapViewPage {
@ViewChild('content') content: Content;
constructor(){
}

    ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.content.ionScroll.subscribe((event) =>  {
      //console.log('scrolled');
        //var pacContainer = document.body.querySelector('.pac-container');
        const pacContainer = document.querySelector<HTMLElement>('.pac-container');
        pacContainer.style.display  = "none";
       });
  }
 }
```

Comment: Does it work with plain HTML code ?

Comment: If yes please share your code snippet